# Getting both max and min sum values on mysql

Tags: mysql

Good day everyone I would like a query that can give me both maximum and minimum sum values. Specifically i have the following tables:

PRODUCT

```
_____________________________
productID | categoryID| name|
__________|___________|_____|
1          1           "name1"       
2          1           "name2"     
3          1           "name3"    
4          2           "name4"        
5          2           "name5"     
6          1           "name6"        
7          2           "name7"           
8          2           "name8"
```

AND:

PURCHASES

```
_____________________________
purchaseID | productID| quantity|
___________|___________|_________|
1          1           12     
2          2           13     
3          4           55    
4          4           66       
5          5           99     
6          6           99      
7          5           88           
8          7           12
```

so basically i have to show the product that was bought the most and the product that was bought the least.. T have tried this:

```
SELECT pr.name, max(sum(p2.quantity))
FROM  purchase as p2, product as pr
WHERE p2.IDproduct=pr.IDproduct 
Group by p2.IDproduct desc
```

but I get Error Code 1111: Invalid use of group function.

Comment: What are posothta onoma_proiontos etc? It would help if you edited your query to match the schema you posted above.

Comment: What happens when there is a tie?  Do you want to select all tying max/min records, or only some subset of them?  If the latter, which subset?

Answer (score 4):

For max Product

```
select t.name,max(t.sum1) MaxProduct
FROM
(SELECT a.name, sum(b.quantity) sum1
FROM  PRODUCT a
INNER JOIN PURCHASES b
ON a.productID = b.productID
GROUP BY a.productID  )t
group by t.name order by MaxProduct desc limit 1
```

FOR COMBINE RESULT

```
(select t.name,max(t.sum1) MaxProduct
FROM
(SELECT a.name, sum(b.quantity) sum1
FROM  PRODUCT a
INNER JOIN PURCHASES b
ON a.productID = b.productID
GROUP BY a.productID  )t
group by t.name order by MaxProduct desc limit 1)
UNION ALL
(select t1.name,min(t1.sum1) MaxProduct
FROM
(SELECT a.name, sum(b.quantity) sum1
FROM  PRODUCT a
INNER JOIN PURCHASES b
ON a.productID = b.productID
GROUP BY a.productID  )t1
group by t1.name order by MaxProduct asc limit 1)
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a767a/13)**

Comment: Thanks @WouterVanherck, for suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Hacky, but it works

```
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(pur.quantity) quant, 
    prod.name name
  FROM Purchases pur
  INNER JOIN Products prod
    ON prod.productID = pur.productID
  GROUP BY pur.productID
  ORDER BY quant DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(pur.quantity) quant, 
    prod.name name
  FROM Purchases pur
  INNER JOIN Products prod
    ON prod.productID = pur.productID
  GROUP BY pur.productID
  ORDER BY quant ASC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed5fd3/24/0)

Answer (score 0):

As I received a `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery as an error` error.

For others encountering the problem of using the `SUM` function inside of a `MAX` function, but not having the same issue as OP, based on **Luv**'s answer, I was able to convert the following `Scalar-valued function`:

```
SELECT @MinMaxValue = MAX(SUM(ArtikelM.Omzet)/SUM(ArtikelM.Aantal))
FROM ArtikelM
    INNER JOIN Klanten
        ON ArtikelM.KlantenId = Klanten.KlantenId
    WHERE ArtikelId = @ArtikelId
        AND Klanten.KlantTypeCategorie = @KlantType
        AND Klanten.KlantGrootteCategorie = @KlantGrootte
        AND ArtikelM.Jaar = @Jaar
```

to

```
SELECT @MinMaxValue = MAX(selectedsum.sumx)
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(ArtikelM.Omzet)/SUM(ArtikelM.Aantal) AS sumx
    FROM ArtikelM
    INNER JOIN Klanten
        ON ArtikelM.KlantenId = Klanten.KlantenId
    WHERE ArtikelId = @ArtikelId
        AND Klanten.KlantTypeCategorie = @KlantType
        AND Klanten.KlantGrootteCategorie = @KlantGrootte
        AND ArtikelM.Jaar = @Jaar
) AS selectedsum
```

or if `ArtikelM.Aantal` could be zero

```
SELECT sumx =
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(ArtikelM.Aantal) > 0
        THEN SUM(ArtikelM.Omzet)/SUM(ArtikelM.Aantal)
        ELSE MIN(Leverancier.FactPrijs)
    END
FROM ArtikelM
INNER JOIN Leverancier
    ON ArtikelM.LevId = Leverancier.LevId
INNER JOIN Klanten
    ON ArtikelM.KlantenId = Klanten.KlantenId
WHERE ArtikelId = @ArtikelId
    AND Klanten.KlantTypeCategorie = @KlantType
    AND Klanten.KlantGrootteCategorie = @KlantGrootte
    AND ArtikelM.Jaar = @Jaar
) AS selectedsum
```

I think this might help out others too

Answer (score -1):

```
Select max(product_id), min(product_id) 
from Purchases Where Product_id In
(select product_id, Sum(quantity) from Purchases Group by product_id)
```